# Python string to list best practice

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string like this `"['first', 'sec', 'third']"`

What would be the best way to convert this to a list of strings ie. `['first', 'sec', 'third']`

Comment: Best way would be to use a known serialization format, like json.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd use [`literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), it's safe:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the
>   values oneself.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("['first', 'sec', 'third']")
['first', 'sec', 'third']
```

It doesn't eval anything except literal expressions:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('"hello".upper()')
...
ValueError: malformed string

>>> ast.literal_eval('"hello"+" world"')
...
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe, I've been using this but I am curious to see what people think, other methods etc.

Comment: +1 - This is the best way to do it, as `ast.literal_eval()` is safe, as opposed to `eval()`. That said, the best option is probably to store your data in a more standardised format, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If <strike>they're always formatted as you say</strike> all the strings are quoted in the same fashion, a simple split should do it, too:

```
"['first', 'sec', 'third']".split("'")[1::2]
```

This solution is much more fragile, as it will support only a single quoting style.

It is considerably faster, though.

```
%timeit "['first', 'sec', 'third']".split("'")[1::2]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 726 ns per loop

%timeit ast.literal_eval("['first', 'sec', 'third']")
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 us per loop
```

Comment: Cool, but what if the list was `"['first', 'sec', 'third', \"fourth\"]"` or even `L = """['first', 'sec', 'third', "fourth"]"""`

Comment: Nice examples. I'll let the answer live, I hope it aids showing why literal_eval is the better practice.